# How can I search reminders in Google Inbox, but not search emails?

Tags: search, inbox-by-gmail

I am using Google Inbox and I'm looking for all of the reminders in my account with "keyword" in them.

Problem is that "keyword" also shows up in tons of my email (way too many to page through), and I am looking only for reminders, not emails.

Is there a way to search only reminders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can search only for reminders by adding the search operator "is:reminder" to your search.

```
keyword is:reminder
```

If you want only reminders that have not been marked done, add "in:inbox"

```
keyword is:reminder in:inbox
```

Comment: Thank you! How/where did you figure this out?

Comment: Partly from inference from the advanced Gmail search operators (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) and partly from other StackExchange questions

Comment: This is not completely correct. `is:reminder` will return reminders *and email threads with reminders*, and `keyword` will be searched in the reminder text (for reminders) and the email body (for email threads). Try adding any (nonempty) reminder to an email thread after pinning it, identify a keyword that appears in the email body, then search for `is:reminder keyword`. Your email thread will be part of the search results.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get `is:reminder -is:done` to work.

So I used this, and it did what I wanted (all reminders not done, including reminders that aren't related to email):

```
is:reminder is:pinned
```

It renders this link, which you could bookmark or whatever: `inbox.google.com/search/is%3Areminder%20is%3Apinned?pli=1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "is:reminder" operator. To exclude completed from your result, also specify "-is:done".

`keyword is:reminder -is:done`

Answer (score 0):

I've grown frustrated with the "pseudo" query search syntax from Inbox. This is a hack but it works great (for me), when I want to search in a particular section. Here's an example: Say I want to search within my snoozed reminders for the phrase "Validate Warranty":

1. Shift m (to focus on the side bar)
2. Go down to the "Snoozed" section
3. Focus on the 1st item (Right arrow)
4. Press the "End" key (that should force loading a lot if not all of your items)
5. Use your "find in page" feature from your browser.

(Please notice that these instructions assume you have keyboard shortcuts enabled).

I know this is not ideal, but I feel like Inbox has been semi-abandoned by the Google folks; this is a hack.